# When reading input from a file, my program is not reading the integers correctly

Tags: c

I've got a text file that I am supposed to read with file input/output techniques:

```
47900       31007
34500        9100
57984       14822
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 FILE *input;
 int CA1;
 int CA2;
 int CA3;
 int CL1;
 int CL2;
 int CL3;


int main (void)
{
    input = fopen("c:\\class\\currentratio.txt","r");
    fscanf(input,"%d %d\n", &CA1, &CL1);
    fscanf(input, "%d %d\n", &CA2, &CL2);
    fscanf(input, "%d %d\n", &CA3, &CL3);
    printf("%d", &CA1);
    fclose(input);
    return 0;
}
```

When I print the numbers, they are

> 4229680, 4229704, 4229744, 4229712, 4229664, and 4229720.

Comment: Which language are you actually using? Tag that, and not some other language.

Comment: with `printf("%d", &CA1);` you are trying to print the address, and not the value, of the variable `CA1`. Try to remove the `&` character ;)

Comment: also, try to compile your code with flags like `-Wall` to display warning messages if any. For example, your code compiles with a format warning: `code.c:17:3: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]   printf("%d", &CA1)`

Answer (score 6):

You are printing the address of the variable and not its value.
Get rid of the address: `printf("%d", CA1);`

Also, you are not checking whether opening the file succeeded. You should handle it, especially in case something doesn't work as expected.

```
if(!input)
{
    printf("Could not open the file specified.");
    return -1;
}
```